# Algorithm to find the IP address of the Wireless en1

Tags: c, networking

```
struct ifaddrs *addrs, *temp_addr;
int result;

result=getifaddrs(&addrs);
if(result != 0) {
    perror("getifaddrs");
}
else { // successful
    temp_addr=addrs;
    while(temp_addr != NULL) {
        if(strcmp(temp_addr->ifa_name, "en1") == 0) {

        }  //if en1
    }   //while loop
}
```

The `getifaddrs` function will get the interfaces for `en0`, `en1`, `lo0`, ...etc but I want to only to narrow it down to Ip address of `en1`.  So, I have the above algorithm but something is missing. anyone have any inputs for improve the above so the IP address of en1 can be found.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>

struct ifaddrs *ifaddr, *ifa;
int family;

if (getifaddrs(&ifaddr) == -1) {
    perror("getifaddrs");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
for (ifa = ifaddr; ifa != NULL; ifa = ifa->ifa_next) {
    if (ifa->ifa_addr == NULL)
        continue;
    family = ifa->ifa_addr->sa_family;
    if (0 == strcmp(ifa->ifa_name,"en1" ) && (family == AF_INET)) { // v4
         // en1
    }
}

freeifaddrs(ifaddr);
```